# MongoDB dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Okay so here is my first function in my image display code:

```
function init() {

socket.on('getPictures', function(data) {

images = data;


loadImages();
});


console.log("loading");
socket.emit('getPictures');
}
```

The 'getPictures' call returns every document in my database using db.collection.find({}). These documents have properties like name, source(which is a 64 bit string), and some tags that the client can put on each picture. Images is an array that holds all of my documents.

Here is the mongo side code:

```
socket.on('getPictures', function() {
  console.log("getting pictures");
    Picture.find({}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else
      io.emit('getPictures', data);
     });
    });
```

By using the db.collection.find({}) method I'm receiving all my pictures at once and my program has a ridiculous loading time(because there are a lot of pictures). Is there any way I can load once document at a time from mongo and then place it into Images? Is there some way mongo can tell if It has completed the query of a certain document? If so, I already have methods dynamically create and draw each canvas from images, so I could basically eliminate they heavy loading time.

I'm really new to javascript(and programming) so I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information. I'm trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: You can add a route that displays a specific image by it's id. Something like `/display/:_id` and then query the DB for the image with that id.

Comment: It's not really clear what programming issue you are trying to solve; some example code and a clearer explanation would help. It sounds like you are perhaps trying to return multiple string encoded images from a MongoDB query, and then render those images on your website. Since you are already able to load "either one image or all of them", what is the actual technical problem?

Comment: The problem is that I want all of the images, but loading them all in bulk proves to be too slow. Each image is being drawn on a canvas when it gets returned from mongo, but only once all of them have been returned and placed into an array. I was wondering if there was a way to query one image string at a time so that the canvases would  dynamically appear. So I guess the technical problem would be that there is a significant loading time in my program that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two useful approaches occur to me. First, you could use the fact that Mongoose (I am guessing you are using Mongoose from the code) returns a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) as an argument to the callback to send the images singly or in batches as they are returned from the database query. You can control the batch size to find the right balance. Modifying your code schematically,

```
socket.on('getPictures', function() {
    console.log("getting pictures");
    Picture.find({}, function(err, cursor) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                io.emit('aPicture', doc);
            });
    });
});
```

Then you draw each picture as it is received in the client, keyed off the `aPicture` socket event. You can send batches rather than single pictures by modifying the `find()` callback to accumulate an array or something before sending to the client.

The other approach depends on a couple of assumptions: first, that your client program is a browser and, second, that you are displaying the images with a simple `<img src=>` sort of HTML tag. Browsers are optimized to load and render lots of these tags in parallel since most modern websites have pages with many images. In this situation, you could get all the results as you're doing now, but just send back the `_id` or some other unique identifier to the client. Then have another url you can call, like `/images/:_id`, that will look up and respond with the binary data for the image, so you can make a dynamic image tag like `<img src="/images/my_dog_ralphie.jpg">`. You can make a lot of these in sequence, using jQuery or something, and then they will all load and render the actual image asynchronously and in parallel with the details handled by the browser. I can't get too specific with code because I don't know the whole technology stack for your application.